# Laravel: connecting the AWS ElasticCache Redis is timing out

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I am working on a Laravel application. I using Redis and I am using AWS ElasticCache service for that. I am trying to connect to the Redis from my Laravel application. But it is timing out. This is what I have done.

I installed the Predis library by running the following command.

```
composer require predis/predis
```

Then I created a Redis instance in the ElastiCache service console enabling AUTH setting my password token.

Then I set the variables in the .env files.

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
REDIS_CLIENT=predis
REDIS_HOST=master.laravelredistest.8sm3xo.euw1.cache.amazonaws.com
REDIS_PASSWORD=mypassword
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

When I run the code to connect to the Redis, I got the following error.

```
Operation timed out [tcp://master.laravelredistest.8sm3xo.euw1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379]
```

What is missing with my configuration and how can I fix it?

I also updated the security group of Redis to allow the EC2 instance's security group in the inbound rules as follows:

[image]

I am getting this error this time:

[image]

I edited the SG of Redis to add the following inbound rule too.

[image]

The security groups are in the same VPC too as you can see in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Have you allowed inbound access to the security group from your instance?

Comment: Hi, I am using Auth enabled mode. Can I not connect just using password? I am deploying my application to EB. That is going to be extra configuration.

Comment: You also need to have inbound access via security group :)

Comment: Hi...did you fix this...appreciate if you share your solution how to you fix it...I have the same issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a security group issue causing the timeout.

Elasticache clusters are always private so if you're using a public ip address, this will need to be updated to be the private ip address range of your instance/subnet/VPC.

An Elasticache cluster is a resource in your VPC, therefore network transit needs to be allowed for the cluster to be accessible.

More information is available in the [Accessing Your Cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/accessing-elasticache.html) page.

> Additional Configuration

This is the issue. I also needed to delete the existing Redis instance and create another one without AUTH token enabled.

Comment: Hi, I updated the security group's inbound rules of EC2 instance too. But it is still not working.

Comment: The elasticache cluster needs the security group changes, not the EC2 :)

Comment: Hi @Chris, I updated the Security Group of Redis too. I updated the question. I am getting Gateway timeout error and it is still not working.

Comment: Hmm, to confirm you have not changed the NACLs in your instance? And the elasticache cluster shares the same VPC your application is in? Could you try allowing inbound 0.0.0.0/0 for tcp port 6379 just to test? Also to confirm it is running on port 6379 (you can see this in the console)

Comment: I don't think I have changed NACLs because I have not touched any of those settings yet. "allowing inbound 0.0.0.0/0 for tcp port 6379" means I have to update the security of Redis or EC2 instance?

Comment: Yes, basically want to make sure that IP is not restricting security group for some reason

Comment: Security group of Redis or EC2? Which SG do I need to update?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217701/discussion-between-chris-williams-and-wai-yan-hein).